# ¿Cómo puedo sumar los valores de un mismo campo previamente obtenido? - TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, table, angular-datatables

Soy algo nuevo en esto, y no he podido encontrar una solución. Me gustaría sumar los valores de un campo llamado `Towel`, estoy usando una tabla dinámica en donde obtengo el campo a partir de otras funciones, utilizo Angular y Firestore.

El campo lo obtengo y lo almaceno en:

```
item10: string = 'Towel';
```

En donde para poder sumar, estaba usando este código:

```
  view() {
this.total = this.transactions.map(t => t.item10).reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
return this.total;   }
```

Sé que si escribo `t.Towel`  en vez de `t.item10` me suma correctamente, pero como el valor `Towel` es un valor que el usuario ingresa, hace que estos datos sean dinámicos.

La idea es usar la variable `item10`.

Adjunto un stackblitz que hice como ejemplo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cpvwqw?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-multiple-header-footer-example.ts

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: El campo `item10` es de tipo cadena (`string`): `item10: string = 'Towel';` Luego obtienes un `Array` cuando haces lo siguiente: `this.transactions.map(t => t.item10)`. Todos los elementos de este `Array` son cadenas cuyo valor es `Towel`, como lo siguiente: `[ 'Towel', 'Towel', ... ]`. Sobre este `Array` estás aplicando el método `reduce()` que devuelve la "suma" de sus elementos, con un elemento inicial establecido en 0. Pero al ser todos los elementos de tipo cadena, el resultado es una concatenación: `0TowelTowelTowel...'. ¿Logras ver el error ahora? Saludos

Comment: Si, es que no se si habrá alguna forma de verlo como si fuera [key: valor], donde el item10 seria la key para poder buscar todos sus valores. No se si se puede hacer eso, talvez me estoy confundiendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicación en el código:

```
  item10: string = 'Towel';

  transactions: Transaction[] = [
    {id: 'B1', Towel: 4},
    {id: 'B2', Towel: 5},
    {id: 'B3', Towel: 2},
    {id: 'B4', Towel: 4},
    {id: 'B5', abc: 25}, // aquí no existe Towel así que devolverá undefined
    {id: 'B6', Towel: 15},
  ];

  total:number = 0;
  view() {
    this.total = 
    this.transactions
    // crear arreglo con los valores de la propiedad Towel
    // si el objeto no tiene la propiedad Towel entonces habrá valores
    // undefined entonces se usa el operador ?? para retornar un 0 donde Towel 
    //sea undefined
    .map(t => t[this.item10] ?? 0)
    .reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
    return this.total;
  }
```

Comment: Mil gracias! lo del operador ?? lo desconocía y justo eso era lo que me faltaba

Answer (score 0):

Puedes acceder a la clave dinamicamente:

```
this.total = this.transactions
          .map(t => t[this.item10] ?? 0) // aqui el cambio
          .reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puede usar la desestructuración, que puede ayudarlo a obtener solo el valor que desea del objeto que recibió en el map. Haz algo como esto:

```js
transactions = [
    {id: 'B1', Towel: 4},
    {id: 'B2', Towel: 5},
    {id: 'B3', Towel: 2},
    {id: 'B4', Towel: 4},
    {id: 'B5', Towel: 25},
    {id: 'B6', Towel: 15},
  ];

function view() {
    const total = transactions.map(({Towel}) => Towel).reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
    return total;
  }

console.log(view());
```

En su archivo `.ts` reemplace este código:

```
view() {
    this.total = this.transactions.map(({Towel}) => Towel).reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
    return this.total;
  }
```